# Aggregating files for the second time not working in Mule 3.2

Tags: mule

I have upgraded from mule 3.2.1 to 3.3.1 and I am facing following problem. 
I am using the custom Aggregator and custom transformer for aggregating multiple files for processing. The problem is that after first time aggregation when I am dropping another set of files, only transformer class is called and no other component is getting execute. There is no error on console either. 
When I restart the mule, again the process is executing for the first time only.

**My transformer class is :**

```
public class FileCorrelationTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

      @Override
      public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String arg1)
                  throws TransformerException {
            System.out.println("FileCorelationTransformer called");
            System.out.println("=============================");
            System.out.println("Extract Name = "
                        + message.getOutboundProperty("originalFilename"));

            final String fileName = message.getOutboundProperty("filename");

            final String extractName = Generate.extractName(fileName);
            final ArrayList<ExtractVO> extractVOs = ExtractDAO.getInstance()
                        .load(extractName);

            System.out.println("Group Size: " + extractVOs.get(0).getNoOfParts());
            System.out.println("=============================");
            message.setCorrelationId(extractName);
            message.setCorrelationGroupSize(extractVOs.get(0).getNoOfParts());
            return message;
      }
}
```

**My aggregator class is :**

```
public class FileCollectionAggregator extends AbstractAggregator {

      @Override
      protected EventCorrelatorCallback getCorrelatorCallback(
                  MuleContext muleContext) {
            return new CollectionCorrelatorCallback(muleContext, false, "") {
                  @Override
                  public MuleEvent aggregateEvents(EventGroup events)
                              throws AggregationException {
                        CopyOnWriteArrayList<File> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<File>();
                        try {
                              for (Iterator<MuleEvent> iterator = events.iterator(); iterator
                                          .hasNext();) {
                                    MuleEvent event = iterator.next();
                                    try {
                                          list.add(new File(event.transformMessageToString()));
                                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                                          throw new AggregationException(events, null, e);
                                    }
                              }
                        } catch (ObjectStoreException e) {
                              throw new AggregationException(events, null, e);
                        }
                        return new DefaultMuleEvent(new DefaultMuleMessage(list,
                                    muleContext), events.getMessageCollectionEvent());
                  }
            };
      }
}
```

**My mule flow is :**

```
<vm:connector name="ConnectorSinglePartMonthly"
            dynamicNotification="true" doc:name="VM" />

      <custom-transformer
            class="com.transformers.FileCorrelationTransformer" name="fileMultiPartCorrelationTransformer"
            doc:name="Java" />

      <flow name="CountTP" doc:name="CountTP">
            <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:/test/input"
                  connector-ref="fileConnector" doc:name="Count CSV">
                  <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="UGJERT[0-9]*.csv"
                        caseSensitive="false" />
            </file:inbound-endpoint>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="ConnectorMultiPartMonthly"
                  path="monthlyMultiPartFiles" transformer-refs="fileMultiPartCorrelationTransformer"
                  doc:name="TP Multi VM Out" />
            <logger message="Done with the Flow!" doc:name="Logger" />
      </flow>

      <flow name="MultiPartMonthlyFlow" doc:name="MultiPartMonthlyFlow">
            <vm:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="ConnectorMultiPartMonthly"
                  path="monthlyMultiPartFiles" doc:name="TP Multi Monthly VM In" />

            <custom-aggregator class="com.routing.FileCollectionAggregator"
                  doc:name="Custom Aggregator" />

              <component doc:name="Csv Reader">
                   <prototype-object
                        class="com.utility.CsvReader" />
                </component>

      </flow>
```

**My console Output is :**

**After First Execution**

```
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,296 [[test].fileConnector.receiver.05] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\test\input\UGJERT12.csv
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,311 [[test].fileConnector.receiver.05] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\test\input\UGJERT22.csv
FileCorelationTransformer called
FileCorelationTransformer called
=============================
=============================
Extract Name = UGJERT12.csv
Extract Name = UGJERT22.csv
Group Size: 2
=============================
Group Size: 2
=============================
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,421 [[test].ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.6508195'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,421 [[test].ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.29350820'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,421 [[test].ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.6508195'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-07-19 16:51:02,421 [[test].ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'ConnectorMultiPartMonthly.dispatcher.29350820'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher

Process execution starts and extractName is = UGJERT
```

**After Second Execution**

```
INFO  2013-07-19 16:53:18,530 [[test].fileConnector.receiver.09] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\test\input\UGJERT12.csv
INFO  2013-07-19 16:53:18,546 [[test].fileConnector.receiver.09] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\test\input\UGJERT22.csv
FileCorelationTransformer called
=============================
Extract Name = UGJERT12.csv
Group Size: 2
=============================
FileCorelationTransformer called
=============================
Extract Name = UGJERT22.csv
Group Size: 2
=============================
```

For every set of files, the correlation id is the name of the file which is unique across different set of files. Cannot anyone tell me what Is wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't understand the need for a `custom-aggregator` here: the transformer sets the right correlation ID and group sizes, so a standard `collection-aggregator` should be able to group the messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse a correlation id because that's kept on the object store (that explains why it works again if you restart Mule).
You have to use a different correlation id for each of the aggregation groups.

Comment: In custom transformer I am setting the correlationid as the file name. For ex: I have 2 files to aggregate abcdef12.csv and abcdef22.csv, I am setting correlation id as abcdef and size is 2. This is different for every set of files. SO in the beginning of every process, custom transformer is called and correlation id is set.

Comment: Yes you can't reuse a correlation id, However you may add salt (time  windows based valu) to correlation id every time and make it unique ..